# How to remove Item from QListWidget

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm stuck using myItem.hide() method every time I need to remove Item from QListWidget list. Hiding an item instead of deleting/removing makes things unnecessary complex. I would appreciate if you show me how to delete Item from ListWidget permanently.

[image]

---

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyApp(object):    
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()                
        self.mainWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.mainWidget.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

        self.hLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.mainLayout.insertLayout(0, self.hLayout)
        self.listA=QtGui.QListWidget()
        for i in range(3):
            self.listA.addItem('Item '+str(i))
        self.hLayout.addWidget(self.listA)

        self.buttonGroupbox = QtGui.QGroupBox()
        self.buttonlayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.buttonGroupbox.setLayout(self.buttonlayout)

        okButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Remove Selected')
        okButton.clicked.connect(self.removeSel)
        self.buttonlayout.addWidget(okButton)

        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.buttonGroupbox)
        self.mainWidget.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    def removeSel(self):
        listItems=self.listA.selectedItems()
        if not listItems: return        
        for item in listItems:
            print type(item), dir(item)
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I don't know why but removeItemWidget don't work as expected. You have to use take item instead:

```
def removeSel(self):
    listItems=self.listA.selectedItems()
    if not listItems: return        
    for item in listItems:
       self.listA.takeItem(self.listA.row(item))
```

Comment: I don't recall why but when I had to do the same, I did it in two steps: get the rows to remove. Sort them in descending order. Do the `takeItem(row)` for each row. Maybe I was just tired, or there might be an issue with multiple selection. I don't have the time to try, so just be careful :).

Comment: `removeItemWidget` doesn't remove item from a `QListWidget` because it is not intended to do it. It is made to remove a widget that is set to an item of the `QListWidget`. `takeItem(row)` is indeed the correct way to remove an item from the list.

Answer (score 2):

Posting here an example showing how to implement same approach but now applied to `QTreeWidget` which a bit more involved than `QListWidget`.

### [image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyApp(object):    
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()                
        self.mainWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.mainWidget.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

        self.hLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.mainLayout.insertLayout(0, self.hLayout)


        self.listA=QtGui.QTreeWidget()
        self.listA.setColumnCount(3)
        self.listA.setHeaderLabels(['Checkbox','Name','Data'])
        for i in range(3):
            item=QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem()
            item.setCheckState(0,QtCore.Qt.Checked)
            item.setText(1, 'Item '+str(i))
            item.setData(2, QtCore.Qt.UserRole, id(item) )
            item.setText(2, str(id(item) ) )
            self.listA.addTopLevelItem(item)

        self.hLayout.addWidget(self.listA)

        self.buttonGroupbox = QtGui.QGroupBox()
        self.buttonlayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.buttonGroupbox.setLayout(self.buttonlayout)

        okButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Remove Selected')
        okButton.clicked.connect(self.removeSel)
        self.buttonlayout.addWidget(okButton)

        getDataButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Get Items Data')
        getDataButton.clicked.connect(self.getItemsData)
        self.buttonlayout.addWidget(getDataButton)

        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.buttonGroupbox)
        self.mainWidget.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    def removeSel(self):
        listItems=self.listA.selectedItems()
        if not listItems: return   
        for item in listItems:
            itemIndex=self.listA.indexOfTopLevelItem(item)
            self.listA.takeTopLevelItem(itemIndex)
        print '\n\t Number of items remaining', self.listA.topLevelItemCount()

    def getItemsData(self):
        for i in range(self.listA.topLevelItemCount()):
            item=self.listA.topLevelItem(i)
            itmData=item.data(2, QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
            itemId=itmData.toPyObject()
            print '\n\t Item Id Stored as Item Data:', itemId, 'Item Checkbox State:', item.checkState(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MyApp()
```

Answer (score 1):

A ListWidget is a list of ListWidgetItems. A ListWidgetItems can be assigned a custom widget to override the default, so removeItemWidget() only removes the custom widget. Hence the need for takeItem, which pops the item from the list and returns it (similar to how a python list works)